# Icons editable in Visual Studio, but appear blank in other editors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, icons

Odd one, this. The project I'm working on includes some small icons (.ico file type) in a Windows resource (.rc) file, all 10x10 black on transparent.

Opening these icons in Visual Studio 2010 correctly brings up the icon editor, showing the icon in salmon-pink on teal-green. The icon's properties in VS show it as "10x10, 4 bit, BMP". The app that includes the icons displays them fine.

However, I cannot view or edit them in external editors! Windows 7 explorer's thumbnail view is blank white; MS Paint also loads them as 10x10 blank white images. Paint.Net (with the [.ico plugin](http://www.dragonblogger.com/edit-save-ico-images-paintnet/)) thinks they're 10x10 transparent images. Windows file properties reports them as 10x10, 32-bit icons.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An icon contains 3 distinct bitmaps.  Two monochrome ones and, in your case, a 4bpp bitmap.  The monochrome bitmaps determine how the pixels are displayed.  One of them determines whether a pixel is transparent, it shows up as teal green in the icon editor.  The other determines whether a pixel is actually the background pixel inverted, it shows up as pink salmon in the icon editor.

So if you only see teal and pink then your 4bpp bitmap does not contribute anything at all to the visible icon.  Whatever other icon viewer you are using to look at the icon is tripped up by that.  Which is not unusual, inverting background pixels made only sense in the early days of Windows, back when displays had a very limited number of colors.  Like 4bpp.

Fix it by using real colors in the 4bpp bitmap.  Or don't worry about it if you are always displaying the icon on a well known background.  Which is not typical btw, the user can change the color scheme setting for the window title bar for example.  Or change the wall paper image for the desktop.  The resulting icon color will be pretty random.